Open a camera View in .NET MAUI with activated Flash not working
I am developing an App in .NET MAUI and use the Camera.MAUI NuGet package to take photos with live preview and to scan barcodes. Both works really well, but I have troubles implementing a specific feature: Opening the Camera View for barcode scanning with an activated Flash.
There is a separate Page in our App that is used for scanning barcodes. It contains a few UI elements like the CameraView from Camera.MAUI, a button to toggle the Flash state, and a preview of what was scanned. The Camera View looks like this in XAML.
<camera:CameraView x:Name="CameraView"
                   WidthRequest="360" 
                   HeightRequest="240"
                   Margin="0,20,0,0"
                   CamerasLoaded="CameraViewCamerasLoaded"
                   BarCodeDetectionEnabled="True"
                   TorchEnabled="{Binding Path=UseFlash}"
                   FlashMode="Enabled"
                   BarcodeDetected="CameraViewBarcodeDetected" />

The camera's Flash is bound to UseFlash. I can toggle this Boolean property by pressing a button on the Page. This toggles the Flash as expected and works perfectly.
I react to the camera loaded event to make sure everything is properly initilized. Code is based on guides and sample code.
private void CameraViewCamerasLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"{this}.CameraViewCamerasLoaded > {nameof(sender)} = {sender}, {nameof(e)} = {e}");

    if (CameraView.Cameras.Count > 0)
    {
        CameraView.Camera = CameraView.Cameras.First();

        MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await CameraView.StopCameraAsync();
            await CameraView.StartCameraAsync();
        });
    }
}

The only code-behind alteration I did for the CameraView is
CameraView.BarCodeDecoder = new ZXingBarcodeDecoder();

My problem
However, I do not get the Page to be started with an activated Flash.
Here is what I tried.
Setting the UseFlash property to true in the constructor is just ignored.
var deviceService = _serviceProvider.GetService<IDeviceService>();
if (deviceService != null)
{
    UseFlash = deviceService.GetDefaultCameraFlashState();
}

Using the code above to set default state causes a NullReference exception if it is executed in the MainThread (see below), or is just ignored otherwise.
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    ...
});

